# Get cell background color with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I wanted to convert a code that already written in VBA that get cell background as RGB string into C#, here is VBA code for the background color:

```
Public Function bRGB(rng As Range)
    Dim intColor As Long
    Dim rgb As String
    Dim r, g, b As Long
    intColor = rng.Interior.Color
    r = intColor And 255
    g = intColor \ 256 And 255
    b = intColor \ 256 ^ 2 And 255
    bRGB = r & ";" & g & ";" & b
End Function
```

to get the background in C# I tried:

```
string BackgroundColor = (string.Format(Mysheet.GetRow(CurrRow).GetCell(4).CellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor.RGB.ToString()));
```

Mysheet is Isheet that I read from my excel file, and the CurrRow is the current row as I do it in for loop.
I got an Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**EDIT:** I solved the exception but I still getting null. any help?

Comment: Use a breakpoint and watch for what object is null

Comment: Note that in VBA `Dim r, g, b As Long` declares only `b` as `Long` but `r` and `g` as `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long`.

Comment: the VBA is old code that I don't use anymore. However, now I try to get same return as bRGB and fRGB functions of VBA.

Comment: Why do you use the [String.Format Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) in your first code? Try without it. And what is `Mysheet` and `CurrRow`? This is not shown in your code.

Comment: I edited my question to show what I mean by Mysheet and CurrRow.

Comment: @PortlandRunner do you mean it will return r;g;b string?

Comment: @PortlandRunner, I used the ```Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myBytearray, 0, myByteArray.length)``` But I still get same exception when the compiler reach line ```return (font as XSSFFont).GetXSSFColor().RGB;```